# PHP libraries in extensions

Tags: extension, php

I've seen the conversation at: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=27981.0. But I was wondering if anyone had experienced successfully embedding a PHP library in an extension.

Specifically I want to include the PHP Simple DOM Parser. Any instructions/guidance? That contains a simple php file and a folder of files that it uses.

Answer (score 1):

The [OmniPay extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor) comes to mind as an extension built around a library.  Looking quickly, it seems like the sensible answer is "Use Composer".

Comment: I like it. But I wonder if there's an easier way...